# How to Make the Selected Option Image not Move when React Select Dropdown Menu Opens and Closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

So I have an array of countries and then I map over those in a customOptions object

```
export const customOptions = filteredCountries.map((country) => ({
      value: country,
      label: (
        <div>
            <div>
                <img
                    src={require(`../images/flags/${country.svg}`)}
                    className="flag-image"
                    alt={`${country.name} flag`}
                />
                <span className='country-option'>
                    {country.name} ({country.dialingCode})
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
      ),
}));
```

Now when I come to select an option from the list and it shows where my placeholder was in my React Select drop-down menu the flag image shifts to the left and right, whereas the placeholder sits nice and center...

How can I make it so the selected flag image option sits still like the placeholder?

- Container

```
const placeholderContent = usersCountryFlagSVG ? (
        <img
            src={require(`../images/flags/${usersCountryFlagSVG}`)}
            alt="Flag"
            width="24"
            height="16"
        />
    ) : (
        <img    
            src={GBSVG} 
            alt="Flag" 
            width="24" 
            height="16" 
        />
);

const customStyles = {
        menu: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            width: '360px',
        }),
        container: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            width: '103px',
            marginLeft: '3px',
        }),
        control: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            height: '56.6px',
            minHeight: '0px',
            maxWidth: '83px',
            border: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? '1px solid transparent' : 'transparent',
            borderImage: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? 'linear-gradient(145deg, rgba(54,122,225,1) 48%, rgba(113,168,252,1) 100%)' : 'transparent',
            borderImageSlice: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? '1' : 'transparent',
            ':hover': {
                cursor: 'pointer'
            },
            boxShadow: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? '0 0 0 1.5px #2684FF' : 'transparent',
        }),
        dropdownIndicator: (provided, state)=> ({
            ...provided,
            width: '32.5px',
            height: '20px',
            transform: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? 'rotate(180deg)' : null,
            padding: '0px',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            ':hover': {
                // Add styles for hover here
                // For example, you can change the color on hover:
                fill: '#ff0000', // Change this to your desired color
              },
              '&.menu-is-open': {
                // Add styles for when the menu is open here
                // For example, you can change the color when the menu is open:
                fill: '#00ff00', // Change this to your desired color
              },
        }),
        indicatorSeparator: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'none',
        }),
        indicatorContainer: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        }),
        input: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            caretColor: 'transparent',
        }),
        valueContainer: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'flex',
            flexWrap: 'nowrap',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
        }),
        placeholder: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            marginTop: '2px',
        }),
        singleValue: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            marginTop: '2px',
            minHeight: "100%",
            minWidth: "100%",
        }),
}
```

- Component

```
<Select
  styles={customStyles}
  class="flag-drop-down"
  options={customOptions}
  components={{ DropdownIndicator: CustomDropdownIndicator}}
  placeholder={placeholderContent}
  onChange={setSelectedOption}
  value={selectedOption}
/>
```

I have tried adding flex css props and overflow hidden and text overflow ellipsis to the custom options object, but it still shifted left and right when the menu was open.

Solution/ ideas would be appreciated!

I have tried adding flex css props and overflow hidden and text overflow ellipsis to the custom options object, but it still shifted left and right when the menu was open.

Needed the selected image flag to remain centered without moving.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a codesandbox?

Comment: Just tried, but it would take a while, here is the link to my github -  it is in the confirmYoureNotARobotContainer/Component and the countryDropDownOptions.js in the utils will help.